# Why is bootstrap skipping lines?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttHOI.png

Bootstrap seems to have skipped 11 cols, I'm having trouble with aligning everything.

Comment: Can you please show you code here.

Comment: Please place sample code at: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the `col-md-` named classes `divs` in a `row` class.

For example -

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-5"></div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
```

Go with link for **[more details](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid)**

Answer (score 0):

If you would put your code here we would have a better idea of your problem.

Having said that, I leave you some general tips:

> **Some Bootstrap grid system rules:**
>
> - Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or    .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding
> - Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns
> - Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be    immediate children of rows
> - Predefined classes like .row and .col-sm-4 are available for quickly    making grid layouts
> - Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding.    That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via
>     negative margin on .rows
> - Grid columns are created by specifying the number of 12 available    columns you wish to span. For example, three equal columns would use
>     three .col-sm-4

Here the full info: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Here an snippet example to illustrate:

```css
.show-grid [class^="col-"]{
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  background-color: #EEE;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row show-grid">
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">.col-1</div>
</div>
<div class="row show-grid">
  <div class="col-xs-8">.col-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row show-grid">
  <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row show-grid">
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yuck, copy pasting may be an answer, just not a good one at that :/

Comment: @Darren I like I said I don't know the OP code and while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: That is indeed correct Yandy, but you should look at [W3Fools](http://www.w3fools.com). Just saying an example is a great way to go too ;-)

Comment: @Darren ok I took your advice and I added an example to guide.

Comment: Much better Yandy :) That looks like a respectable answer!